# Unity Android plugin error "AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to write android java plugin that use EncryptedSharedPreferences:

```
public class MyPlugin {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public MyPlugin(Context context) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        MasterKey masterKey = new MasterKey.Builder(context)
                .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
                .build();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                context,
                "secret_shared_prefs",
                masterKey,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
        );
    }

    public void setPreferenceString (String prefKey, String prefValue) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(prefKey, prefValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String getPreferenceString (String prefKey) {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(prefKey, "defaultValue");
    }
```

I build this using android studio and add generated aar file to Unity project.
When i try to create object of this class from Unity I get this error:

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/security/crypto/MasterKey$Builder;
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/security/crypto/MasterKey$Builder;
...
```

Do i need to add some dependency inside Unity?

Im using Unity 2021.3.18.
When i use classic SharedPreferences from plugin everything works fine.